# Bind all entry widgets in a frame to a key

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Is there a way to bind all entry widgets from a frame to a key like `<Return>`?

I tried a workaround like this:

```
frame1.focus_set()
frame1.bind("<Escape>", Exit)
```

But this is kind of useless for me, because the focus is mainly on the entry boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just recognized that binding the childs of a frame is exactly what I needed!

```
    for child in self.frame_gui.winfo_children():
         child.bind('<Return>', self.calculate)
```